# Kendo Grid Field value set by another grid select

Tags: asp.net-mvc

this is the main grid, i am trying to update main grid fields with popup grid selection. please help me.this code will update the main grid by selection of popup. but not set model. so i ddnt get value on controller. how do i solve this issue?

```
<a id="window"></a>
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<IBATechnologies.IBA.Web.Models.AssetLocationViewModel>()
        .Name("GridLocation")
       .Columns(columns =>
{
    //columns.Bound(p => p.UserId).Width(125);
    columns.Bound(p => p.CampanyCode).Width(125);
    columns.Bound(p => p.location1code).Width(165).Filterable(false);
    columns.Bound(p => p.location2code).Width(150).Filterable(false);
    columns.Bound(p => p.locationCode).Width(125);
    columns.Bound(p => p.Name).Width(150);
    columns.Bound(p => p.ShortName).Width(150);
    columns.Bound(p => p.CreatedBy).Width(150);
    columns.Bound(p => p.ModifyBy).Width(150);


    //columns.Bound(p => p.Designation).Width(150);
    columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(200);
})
.ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
.Pageable()

.Sortable()
.Scrollable()
.Selectable()
.Filterable(filterable => filterable
    .Extra(false)
    .Operators(operators => operators
        .ForString(str => str.Clear()
            .StartsWith("Starts with")
            .IsEqualTo("Is equal to")
            .IsNotEqualTo("Is not equal to")
        )))
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:430px;" })
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .PageSize(20)

    //.Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
    .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.locationCode))
    .Create(update => update.Action("AssetLocEditingPopup_Create", "Location"))
        .Read(read => read.Action("AssetLocationEditingPopup_Read", "Location"))
        .Update(update => update.Action("AssetLocEditingPopup_Update", "Location"))

        .Destroy(update => update.Action("AssetLocEditingPopup_Destroy", "Location"))
)




)



   <script type="text/javascript">


    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#GridLocation").on("dblclick", " tbody > tr > td", function () {

        //model.location2code = 100;
        //var grid = $("#GridLocation").data("kendoGrid");
        //var data = grid.datasource.at(0);
        ////data.set("location1code", l1locode);
        //alert(data.location1code);
        //var gridDataArray = $('#GridLocation').data('kendoGrid')._data;
        //var columnDataVector = [];
        //var columnName = 'location1code';
        ////for (var index = 0; index < gridDataArray.length; index++) {
        ////    columnDataVector[index] = gridDataArray[index][columnName];
        ////};
        ////alert(columnDataVector[0]);
        //gridDataArray[0].text("location1code", "frfrf");
        //$("#locapopupWindow").data('kendoWindow').open();
        $("#window").load("@Url.Action("PopupWindow", "Location")");
        //$(this).load("/Shared/_assetLocationPopup");


        $('#GridLocation').data('kendoGrid').refresh()
        //firstItem.dirty = true;  // set it as dirty

        //$('#GridLocation').data().kendoGrid.dataSource.sync();
    });

});
```

this is popup window with grid

```
 @{Html.Kendo().Window()
.Name("locapopupWindow")
.Title("Select Location")
.Draggable()
.Width(500)
.Height(300)
.Actions(actions => actions
.Custom("custom")
.Minimize()
.Maximize()
.Close()

)
.Content(@<text>

  @{Html.Kendo().Grid<IBATechnologies.IBA.Web.Models.AssetLocationViewModel>()
.Name("locationpopupGrid")

       .Columns(columns =>
       {
           columns.Bound(p => p.CampanyCode).Width(125).Visible(false);
           columns.Bound(p => p.location1code).Width(165).Visible(false);
           columns.Bound(p => p.location2code).Width(150).Visible(false);
           columns.Bound(p => p.Name).Width(150);
           columns.Bound(p => p.ShortName).Width(150);
           columns.Bound(p => p.CreatedBy).Width(150).Visible(false);
           columns.Bound(p => p.ModifyBy).Width(150).Visible(false);

       })
.Pageable()
.Sortable()
.Scrollable()

.Selectable()

.Filterable(filterable => filterable
    .Extra(false)
    .Operators(operators => operators
        .ForString(str => str.Clear()
            .StartsWith("Starts with")
            .IsEqualTo("Is equal to")
            .IsNotEqualTo("Is not equal to")
        )))
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:250px;" })

.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .PageSize(10)

    //.Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
    .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.location1code))

    .Create(update => update.Action("Level2LocEditingPopup_Create", "Asset"))
        .Read(read => read.Action("Level2LocationEditingPopup_Read", "Location"))


)

.Render();

}
```

)

```
   .Render();


   }

$(document).ready(function (){

    $("#locationpopupGrid").data("kendoGrid").bind("change", enter code hereonLocationRowSelected);
    $("#locapopupWindow").data("kendoWindow").bind("close", onWindowClose);

    function onLocationRowSelected()
    {
        var grid = $("#locationpopupGrid").data("kendoGrid");
        var selectedItem = grid.dataItem(grid.select());

        orisfunction(selectedItem.location1code, enter code hereselectedItem.location2code);

        $("#locapopupWindow").data("kendoWindow").close();
        $("#locapopupWindow").data("kendoWindow").destroy();

    }
    function orisfunction(l1locode, l2locode)
    {

        var grid = $("#GridLocation").data("kendoGrid");
        var data = grid.dataSource.data()[0];

        // Here I am trying to update grid, here data is shows in grid cell but not update model so i cant get value at controlller
        data.set("location1code", l1locode); 
        data.set("location2code", l2locode);
    }
    function onWindowClose()
    {
        $("#locapopupWindow").data("kendoWindow").destroy();
    }
});
```

please help me

Comment: Can you describe your problem, what you're tying to do, what goes wrong, etc.? Just some code and "Please help me" won't get you any good answers, because nobody will know what your problem is.

Comment: Sorry, I am new here,
    I have a main grid named GridLocation. when iam clik on one cell generates a popup with another grid. and i want update my main grid with the selected values of popuped grid.

Comment: I know you're new here, that's why I'm trying to help you. ;) You can actually edit your question to include the description you just gave.

Comment: Thank you mmgross. Can you please help me?

above code is only script section.

Comment: Sorry, can't help you. I've got no clue about asp.net. Your code seems to be javascript with jQuery though, maybe you should add some tags for that as well?

Comment: @mmgross can you please check now?